# REST and Filtering records

Tags: web-services, rest

I currently have a .NET method that looks like this - `GetUsers(Filter filter)` and this is invoked from the client by sending a SOAP request. As you can probably guess, it takes a bunch of filters and returns a list of users that match those filters. The filters aren't too complicated, they're basically just a set of from date, to date, age, sex etc. and the set of filters I have at any point is static.

I was wondering what the RESTful way of doing this was. I'm guessing I'll have a `Users` resource. Will it be something like `GET /Users?fromDate=11-1-2011&toDate=11-2-2011&age=&sex=M` ? Is there a way to pass it a `Filter` without having to convert it into individual attributes?

I'm consuming this service from a mobile client, so I think the overhead of an extra request that actually creates a filter: `POST filters` is bad UX. Even if we do this, what does `POST filters` even mean? Is that supposed to create a filter record in the database? How would the server keep track of the filter that was just created if my sequence of requests is as follows?

```
POST /filters -- returns a filter
{
    "from-date" : "11-1-2011",
    "to-date" : "11-2-2011",
    "age" : "",
    "sex" : "M"
}


GET /Users?filter=filter_id
```

Apologies if the request came off as being a little confused. I am.

Thanks,
Teja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are doing it just like you had it
GET /Users?fromDate=11-1-2011&toDate=11-2-2011&age=&sex=M

We have 9 querystring values.

I don't see any problem with that

Answer (score 1):

The way I handle it is I do a POST with the body containing the parameters and then I return a redirect to a GET.  What the GET URL looks like is completely up to the server.  If you want to convert the filter into separate query params you can, or if you want to persist a filter and then add a query param that points to the saved filter that's ok too.  The advantage is that you can change your mind at any time and the client doesn't care.

Also, because you are doing a GET you can take advantage of caching which should more than make up for doing the extra retquest.

Comment: I'm working with the response below because .. well it feels easier to just pass in request params than to create / persist a Filter resource and retrieve it and all that. Thanks though.